# GmailR signature

Tags: r, email, dplyr, gmailr

I'm trying to create an email for several companies in order to participate on a survey.

I would like to add my signature on the mail. I've read several forums where they explain the API issues regarding the signature.

However most of these forums have been created for mailr package and not gmailr specifically.

Now, if even with this package we can't add the signature in our mails, then can we at least add inline pictures with the signatures on the mails, using the gm_html_body() function.

Here a reprex.

```
gm_mime() %>% 
  gm_to("xyz@yzs.com") %>% 
  gm_from(" xyz@gmail.com") %>% 
  gm_subject(paste("Invitation")) %>% 
  gm_html_body(body = paste(glue("<p>Estimados Sres. <b>{total[['empresa']][k]}</b></p> \\
                                   <p> </p>\\
                                   <p>Atención Sr.(a) {total[['names']][k]}</p>\\
                                   <p> </p>\\
                                   <p><i>email</i> test no. {k}</p>"),
                             "<p>favor intentar enviarnos un correo siempre a {from}.</p> \\
                                  <p> Grupo focal verde validado </p>",
                                  "<h2> A plot of <b>MotorTrend</b> data <i>(1974)</i></h2>
                                  <img src='LOGO.jpeg'>"),inline = T) %>% 
  gm_attach_file('LOGO.jpeg') %>% 
  gm_create_draft()
```

Comment: Isn't an email signature just more text, usually separated from the email body with a simple `--` on its own line?

Comment: It could be, but there's commonly a company's logo

Comment: Yes, and that is included as an image or emoji in the same way images are included in images are embedded in the body of the email. A signature is nothing special: if you have html for the signature, just append it to the email body after a lone `<br/>--<br/>` or such.

Comment: If you see the code I did include the image. <img src='LOGO.jpeg'> issue is that it doesn't show when rendering the mail

Comment: That's not how it works with `gmailr`, the examples suggest you need `gm_attach_file(.)` and a `cid:label` kind of reference instead of a filename. See https://gmailr.r-lib.org/articles/sending_messages.html#including-images

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://gmailr.r-lib.org/articles/sending_messages.html#including-images), you need to attach the file (you are doing this) and assign an `id=` (missing), and reference that id in the `img` tag (doing this incorrectly).

Perhaps:

```r
gm_mime() %>% 
  gm_to("xyz@yzs.com") %>% 
  gm_from(" xyz@gmail.com") %>% 
  gm_subject(paste("Invitation")) %>% 
  gm_html_body(body = paste(glue('<p>Estimados Sres. <b>{total[['empresa']][k]}</b></p> \\
                                   <p> </p>\\
                                   <p>Atención Sr.(a) {total[['names']][k]}</p>\\
                                   <p> </p>\\
                                   <p><i>email</i> test no. {k}</p>"),
                             "<p>favor intentar enviarnos un correo siempre a {from}.</p> \\
                                  <p> Grupo focal verde validado </p>',
                                  '<h2> A plot of <b>MotorTrend</b> data <i>(1974)</i></h2>
                                  <img src="cid:logo">'),inline = T) %>% 
  gm_attach_file("LOGO.jpeg", id="logo") %>% 
  gm_create_draft()
```

Comment: It's great. Seems to work, problem is that receivers don't see the image in the body. They do see the images but not in the body, they see a blank box. Is it a receiver problem or what?

Comment: Not sure, it could be either. Do these sent emails appear in your `Sent` folder? If so, are the images visible there?

Comment: The images are visible there

Comment: Then the problem is less likely to be related to R, I think.